# What's the difference between 有名【ゆうめい】, 人気【にんき】, and 盛ん【さかん】?

Tags: word-choice

What's the difference between 有名【ゆうめい】, 人気【にんき】, and 盛ん【さかん】? I've been looking for an answer to this question for some time now, but couldn't find one that explains the differences properly. I know that 有名【ゆうめい】 is famous - well-known and that 人気【にんき】 means popular - people think it's good, but I don't know when to use 盛ん【さかん】 and what exactly it means.

Comment: https://kotobank.jp/word/%E7%9B%9B%E3%82%93-509261

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- 有名(な): famous; well-known
- 人気(な): popular
- 盛ん(な): done/enjoyed/happens a lot; highly active; prosperous

盛ん may be translated as "popular", but its basic meaning is "done a lot". For example, 日本では米作りが盛んです does not usually mean rice farming is "popular" in the sense that many people like to do it. It just means rice farming is commonly and actively done by farmers in Japan.